# Music App and database accessing

Tags: android, ios, database

I'm kinda stuck on the implmentation phase of my app. It's a music app that asks a user how he's feeling - sorrow, happiness, heartbreak, nervousness, etc., and it then inputs what it already knows of the user to a database of all songs. The app then chooses and shortlists and plays whatever it sees fit to the situation.

I've already created the music app and the GUI for it, but I'm really stuck at how to access a music database, whether it be online or offline. I've read about Musicbrainz, and I did download the databse although it is actively available online. I do not know how to ask my app to look into it and interact with it, or any other online database for that matter.

Please do provide me with any help if its possible.

Comment: How about integrating with spotify API? Then you just query the spotify API with the data you have about the user and you receive back a suggestion for a song. Do you actually have to PLAY the song? Why not just figure out what song you should play and pass a link to spotify / google music etc.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an API.  Udacity does a pretty good job of teaching this.  You have to sign up for an account but it's all free.  Lesson 2 [here](https://www.udacity.com/course/new-android-fundamentals--ud851) will teach you all about with example code.  Then you'll just have to find an API for music.

Answer (score 0):

A little too much information given, try to be more concise. There are a bunch of different ways about going about this. You can connect to a database directly through SQL or MySQL but you would need access to the DB creds. Best option is to use an API. There will be plenty of information on music APIs if you google it.

P.S. Only ask a question if you can't find an answer elsewhere and this type of question has been asked countless times.